# How to call a function from a seperate class inside a feature file?

Tags: python, bdd

I have seen examples of how to call a function within another class using self. But the problem is my feature file using BDD does not have a class definition.

If this was in another language I would be able to call it using the New operator and use methods from it.

I'm unsure how to do this using Python.

class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test= Test('fdfdf')

    def tested(self, testa, testb):
        return self.test(testa,testb)
```

If I want to use this within a feature file how would I call the tested method above as the .feature just contains steps such as @given etc?

Edit:

At the moment my project structure is like this:

```
├── project
│     ├── steps
│            ├── classes.py
│           
└── .feature files
```

There is no **init**.py file. I think I need to create a **init**.py file and specify the import path to the class from the feature file?

So I need to understand how can I instantiate another class inside a class where there is no class definition, such as if you look at the addressbook.py class how would I instantiate another class within that? kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/…

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you are exactly trying to do. I do BDD testing quite regularly, and I'm just really not sure I understand where your difficulty lies. Can you show a sample of your step function and explain exactly in your code what is not working?

Comment: @idjaw thanks for answering, all I am trying to do is within a step such as given I want to use the method above called tested. This is going to be a middle tier class that will be used by all feature files. Im just unsure how to create an object of the class Test and use the tested method in the feature file, do you understand?

Comment: That's the part I'm not understanding about difficulty calling the `tested` method. You instantiate a class in Python simply by calling `Test` as `Test()`. So, `test_obj = Test()`, and then `test_obj.tested(arg1, arg2)`. Beyond this, I am having difficulty understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @idjaw thanks but when I use this test_obj = Test(), Test() shows as unresolved reference, do i need to import the class somehow? Or is it not recognising it because the Test class is in the folder steps and the feature is outside of that

Comment: OK. You have an entirely different problem than what you are trying to explain. It is hard to give you an explicit answer on what is wrong right now, but ensure that, yes, you have properly imported the module that holds the class you want to instantiate and test. Furthermore, you want to make sure you don't have any "name shadowing". e.g. Accidentally using a name that matches the name of the module you are trying to import, thus causing this error. Also, you want to make sure you are properly importing with respect to your working directory.

Comment: Revise your project structure and ensure that you have properly structured your project (appropriate `__init__.py` where they should be, etc). Edit your question to include the appropriate information to help further diagnose.

Comment: thanks I have edited the above the classes are basically in steps folder and the feature files sit directly under the project

Comment: Is this `Test` class you are trying to access inside `classes.py`? Where exactly are you trying to access the `Test` class with respect to where `classes.py` is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138463/discussion-between-samantha-and-idjaw).

Comment: Sorry I got confused again, the classes.py represents the location of all the classes. Im trying to access Test within a class in the same directory. It shows as  unresolved

Answer (score 1):

Behave uses imports a little differently so I done:

```
from steps.test import Test

 test = Test()
```